# How to format texbox for NIC format in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project in c#. I included the detail of persons. The detail contain name, f/name and NIC number. The NIC number which is a country national identity card and its format is 21201-1234567-7.

Now how I can accomplish this?
Under textboxtextchangeevent I want to perform this task.
I tried the following code but it gives me error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name:startIndex

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string text = textBox2.Text;
        string deshsign = "-";
        string c = text.Insert(5, deshsign);
        textBox2.Text = c;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the text isn't 5 characters in length `text.Insert` will throw the exception. In these situations its much better to use a MaskedTextBox

Comment: can you direct me with example

Comment: Please explain with example .

Comment: Its better if you work out how to learn on your own... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For future readers the solution is, add a MaskedTextBox control to the winform, wpf or asp.net page/form.

Set the MaskedTextBox [Mask](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx) property with the NIC mask:

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00000-0000000-0";
```